# Flow: Update Records Filter Criteria vs Logic Decision

Tags: visual-workflow

I'm working on a flow at present in which it comes to a point where I need to update a record based checking a field value.  The following is a pseudo-summary

At Interview X in my flow

- I add an Update Records data-element

  - Within it I add a Filter.  IF "Category__c" Does Not Equal "Swimming"
  - I then set my field value Category__c to an assignment variable (of type text) which I know by debugging has value "Swimming".
- ON running the flow the update does not occur.

It made me wonder if the Filter criteria applied in the update logic works differently to using a decision?  I presume it doesn't apply the filter at the time of the update after I have already set the value to "Swimming".  I would think the filter is checked before I set the value, before it tries the update.
From the above (if my example makes sense) was using a filter correct as opposed to using a decision logic element?

One other thought was that the variable I am assigning to Category__c is a text variable while the field itself is a picklist. However the value should have matched. Is it correct that no conversion to a picklist is required?

Thanks in advance for any tips on this. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: when you use filter criteria in an Update element - SFDC behind the scenes does a query against the database - so any assignment you have made beforehand that has not been DML'd to the database will be ignored

Comment: Thank you @cropredy for confirming on this.

Answer (score 0):

try with below steps :-

1. Add a decision element to check for category
2. If true then add assignment block to assign/directly assign value in the update element.
3. At the end pass the entire record with Id to update in update element

Comment: Thanks @Priya With regards to passing the record with ID to the update, one thing I'd noted is that an additional field value which I'm updating (not via an assignment but instead directly typed in) works ok. It updates but not the Category__c field which was assigned. Should a text or picklist variable used in an assignment assign the value ok? I would have thought this should be ok.   Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Accepting @cropredy's comment as the answer on the Decision vs Login in Filter Criteria question. Regarding issues with using a variable for assigning to a picklist I'll open a new question on it.

Thanks.